# Sorting products in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: excel, csv, prestashop, e-commerce, prestashop-1.7

I have a Prestashop 1.7 website and I'm importing my products by means of a CSV file. The import works as expected but I can't find any way to set the products order on the CSV file. The only way I found is to manually specifying the order on the admin panel.

Is there any CSV column I can use to specify such ordering?

Comment: What do you mean about "given ordering". You can't change a position of a product in the admin panel. Do you mean products' id?

Comment: I mean setting the products order on the CSV rather than changing it on the admin panel, I have +1000 products

Comment: I still can't get what parameter should be a key in your case. And also I don't understand why do you need this? You have a complex filter in admin panel so you can set up any sorting of products

Comment: I need to place some products before some others. I want some products or be a the end of the list (last page). I also have a lots of products so doing it manually is not an option.  The order in which they appear on the CSV would be perfect but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to switch option "Force all ID numbers" before your import start?

Comment: I see, thank you. I guess I need another column "ID" on my CSV, right?